# Entity framework not updating self-referenced key

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I've got my entity class (which is part of my Entity Framework Code First DbContext)  like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Boss { get; set; }
    public decimal Piotrus { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'm trying to update persons boss like this:

```
using(var db = new DataContext())
{
    var employee = db.Persons.Single(p => p.Name = "Kowalski");
    employee.Boss = db.Persons.Single(p => p.Name = "Malysz");

    db.Entry(employee).State = State.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

While debugging entity seems to be ok. It have right Boss assigned. Even when I tried to get data from current DbContext it looks fine, but in Database property Boss_Id stays still unchanged, while other properties (if were changed) has been modified.

Also everything works okay when I'm creating a person. Assigned boss is stored correctly.

What can cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out `db.Entry(employee).State = State.Modified;`

Comment: Without this line it is not changing normal fields, like `Name` either, so.. only got worse..

Comment: Are you disabling autodetection of changes/entity tracking?

Comment: You shouldn't need to manually set the entity's state to modified, then;